# Paired sample t-test in R: a question of direction

Tags: r, statistics

I have a question about the sign of t in a paired-sample t-test using different data structures, but the same data.  I know that the sign doesn't make a difference in terms of significance, but, it does generally tell the user if there have been decreases over time or increases over time.  So, I need to make sure that the code I provide produces the same results OR, is explained correctly.

I have to explain the results (and code) as an example we're giving users of our software, which uses R (Rdotnet within a C# program) for statistics.  I'm unclear as to the proper order of variables in both methods in R.

**Method 1** uses two matrices

```
## Sets seed for repetitive number generation
set.seed(2820)

## Creates the matrices
preTest <- c(rnorm(100, mean = 145, sd = 9))
postTest <- c(rnorm(100, mean = 138, sd = 8))

## Runs paired-sample T-Test just on two original matrices
t.test(preTest,postTest, paired = TRUE)
```

The results show significance and with the positive t, tells me that there has been a reduction in the mean difference from preTest to PostTest.

> ```
>     Paired t-test
>
> data:  preTest and postTest
> t = 7.1776, df = 99, p-value = 1.322e-10
> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>   6.340533 11.185513
> sample estimates:
> mean of the differences 
>                8.763023
> ```

However, most people are going to get their data not from two matrices, but, from a file with values for BEFORE and AFTER.  I will have these data in a csv and import them during a demo.  So, to mimic this, I need to create data frame in the structure that users of our software are used to seeing.  'pstt' should look like the dataframe I have after I import a csv.

**Method 2:**  uses a flat-file structure

```
## Converts the matrices into a dataframe that looks like the way these 
data are normally stored in a csv or Excel

ID <- c(1:100)
pstt <- data.frame(ID,preTest,postTest)

## Puts the data in a form that can be used by R (grouping var | data var)
pstt2 <- data.frame(
                group = rep(c("preTest","postTest"),each = 100),
                weight = c(preTest, postTest)
                )

## Runs paired-sample T-Test on the newly structured data frame
t.test(weight ~ group, data = pstt2, paired = TRUE)
```

The results for this t-test has the t negative, which may indicate to the user that the variable under study has increased over time.

> ```
>     Paired t-test
>
> data:  weight by group 
> t = -7.1776, df = 99, p-value = 1.322e-10
> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>  -11.185513  -6.340533 
> sample estimates:
> mean of the differences 
>               -8.763023
> ```

Is there a way to define explicitly which group is the BEFORE and which is the AFTER?  Or, do you have to have the AFTER group first in Method 2.

Thanks for any help/explanation.

Here is the full R program that I used:

```
## sets working dir
#  setwd("C:\\Temp\\")

## runs file from command line
#  source("paired_ttest.r",echo=TRUE)

## Sets seed for repetitive number generation
set.seed(2820)

## Creates the matrices
preTest <- c(rnorm(100, mean = 145, sd = 9))
postTest <- c(rnorm(100, mean = 138, sd = 8))
ID <- c(1:100)

## Converts the matrices into a dataframe that looks like the way these 
   data are normally stored
pstt <- data.frame(ID,preTest,postTest)

## Puts the data in a form that can be used by R (grouping var | data var)
pstt2 <- data.frame(
                group = rep(c("preTest","postTest"),each = 100),
                weight = c(preTest, postTest)
                )

print(pstt2)                

## Runs paired-sample T-Test just on two original matrices
#  t.test(preTest,postTest, paired = TRUE)

## Runs paired-sample T-Test on the newly structured data frame
t.test(weight ~ group, data = pstt2, paired = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `group` is a factor, the t.test will use the first level of that factor as the reference level. By default factor levels are sorted alphabetically to "AFTER" would come before "BEFORE" and "postTest" would be come before "preTest". You can explicitly set reference level of a factor with `relevel()`.

```
t.test(weight ~ relevel(group, "preTest"), data = pstt2, paired = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick . . .  "relevel()" is exactly what I was looking for.